# Move Raidset from HP Smart Array P400 to E200

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-smart-array

Is there a way to move a Raidset configured for a Raid0/1 from a HP DL380G5 with a SmartArray **P400** Controller into a DL380G5 with an **E200i**. When I fit them in the new Server it does not recognize any Raidsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array should be portable, as in, the array data exists on the disks. Typically, if you keep the drives in the same order (how many disks are there?), maintaining the same drive arrangement, the new controller should recognize the array. If not, try to upgrade the firmware on the destination E200i controller using the [Current Smart Update Firmware DVD](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=4132832&prodNameId=4132957&swEnvOID=4004&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-98ce7a50a19a4d4994aaad8d0e).

Comment: Funny, I just did this today. Worked fine. I'm using ML350s is the only difference.

Comment: i´ll check the firmware on monday - that´s a good hint!