# Transfer raided drive between to identical HP Proliant DL360 G5

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant

I have two identical HP Proliant DL360 G5 servers with HP Smart Array P400i controllers.  I want to move the drives from one of the servers into the other server.  Will the controller of the new server automatically read the RAID configuration from the drives and be able to function?

Answer (score 4):

Yep.

Try to keep the controllers on similar firmware levels and use the same drive positions on the new server. But HP Smart Array RAID metadata lives on the disks, not the controllers.

Also this:
[Move Raidset from HP Smart Array P400 to E200](https://serverfault.com/questions/218905/move-raidset-from-hp-smart-array-p400-to-e200)

[moving raid 10 to another identical server both on Smart Array 6i controllers](https://serverfault.com/questions/457474/moving-raid-10-to-another-identical-server-both-on-smart-array-6i-controllers)